# javascript global array problem

Tags: javascript

consider a scenario

I have javascript array which is declared as global

for instance:

```
 var globalarray=new Array();
```

next I have two multiple select boxes

- selectboxa
- selectboxb

all the option values inside selectbox are dynamic, 
if I select multiple values from both selectboxa and selectboxb. I collect the selected values in global array.

Important: if I choose values  from  either selectboxa or selectboxb no problem but if I select alternatively from selectboxa and selectboxb  it creates a problem

problem: While saving I collect selected values from array, If I select 4 values from selectboxa and next 3 values from selectbox b like this alternatively I change and finally it contains all values as per global array, but I don't want like that using only one global array and get selectboxa values separately and selectbox b  values separetely at same time it is possible.

If any doubts please me ask me.

Comment: Please format your post sanely.

Comment: What is your problem? The paragraph starting with "problem:" does not seem to describe one.

Comment: Also, there hasn't been any tax on capital letters for years and years. You're allowed to use as many of them in your question as normal English grammar requires.

Comment: even after trying to fix the spelling and some of the grammar, it does not make sense to me

Comment: Why you declare only one array? If you need to save selected values from two selectboxes separately - declare two arrays.

Comment: @ all our mother tongue is not english. so sorry for mistakes which i have committed.

Comment: @Henning - vi er jo ikke alle perfekte linguister ;)

Answer (score 0):

I THINK I know what you want...

```
var globalObject = {
  selecta:[],
  selectb:[]
}
function setSel(sel) {
  globalObject[sel.name].length=0;
  for (var i=sel.selectedIndex, n=0;i<sel.options.length;i++) {
    if (sel.options[i].selected) globalObject[sel.name][n++]=sel.options[i].value;
  }
}

<select name="selecta" onChange="setSel(this)">
.
.
.
<select name="selectb" onChange="setSel(this)">
```

Perhaps this then

```
var globalArray = [];

function setSel(theForm) {
  var sela = form.selecta;
  var selb = form.selectb;
  globalArray.length=0;
  for (var i=0, n=0;;i++) {
    if (sela.options.length<i && sela.options[i].selected) globalArray[n++]="a."+i+":"+sela.options[i].value;
    if (selb.options.length<i && selb.options[i].selected) globalArray[n++]="b."+i+":"+selb.options[i].value;
   }
}

<select name="selecta" onChange="setSel(this.form)">
.
.
.
<select name="selectb" onChange="setSel(this.form)">
```